# inequality and equivalence for norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation

Let $x \in R^m$. 
It is known that $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2\leq \sqrt m\|x\|_{\infty}$.

What the difference between above inequality and if we are saying that $\|x\|_2\sim \sqrt m\|x\|_{\infty}$?

(we say that $f\sim g$, if  $cf \leq g \leq Cf$ for some absolute constants $c,C>0$. Note, f and g may have dimensional dependence).

Why equivalence $\|x\|_2\sim \sqrt m\|x\|_{\infty}$ is not true if vector $x$ is compressible?

(Vector $x$ is k-sparse if the support of the vector $|supp(x)|\leq k$ . Vector is (k,d)-compressible if it is withing Euclidean distance $d$ from the set of all sparse vectors.)

Comment: I guess, it means equivalence.

Comment: It is in general a good idea to not assume that people understand the special notation that you may be using. Could you tell us what $|supp(x)|\leq k$ means? While at it, could you also tell us what $\sim$ means? You guessed that it meant equivalence. There are two problems with it: it seems that you yourself are not sure what it means, and secondly: equivalence can be defined in many ways. For example, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is Lipschitz equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ exactly due to the inequality that you wrote in the first line of your post. This equivalence is independent of vectors.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that the symbol $\sym$ gave different meanings. I've add diffinitions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2\leq \sqrt m\|x\|_{\infty}$ contains specific constants, whereas $\|\cdot\|_2\sim \sqrt m\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, or equivalently  $\|\cdot\|_2\sim \|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, merely says that there *are* such constants. Thus, $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2\leq \sqrt m\|x\|_{\infty}$ implies $\|\cdot\|_2\sim \sqrt m\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ but not vice versa.

Regarding the second question, apart from the fact that equivalence of norms is a statement about all vectors and thus it doesn't make sense, strictly speaking, to speak about whether it's true for specific vectors: If you mean that it's only true if we restrict the norm to certain vectors, then that's wrong; the equivalence holds without restrictions, since it's implied by the correct inequality that you give in the first paragraph, which holds for all vectors.